# Есть ли разница между img и background-image?

Tags: html, css, css3

постоянно сталкиваюсь с проблемой выбора: использовать тэг `img` или на блок завязать `background-image`? Как по мне, `background-image` гораздо удобнее, учитывая `background-size:cover` и `background-position: center`, а с `img` постоянные траблы: то высота скачет в картинках(разные высоты у них, поэтому бывает `whitespace`, то налазят. Это все решается стилями, но бэк мне нравится больше

 **Вопрос** Есть ли разница в их использовании?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts background-size не очень кроссбраузерный. Повсеместность его использования обусловлена вашей аудиторией. Если у вас проект, на котором 10% юзеров сидят под IE < 11 - можете забыть о background-siz'ах, CSS3, flex и придется учиться "любить" img )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Негласные правила говорят нам, что `<img>` следует использовать в том случае, когда эта картинка играет не косметическую роль, а является важной частью контента. Тогда она должна участвовать в разметке документа.

В случае же использования изображения с целью более красивого оформления следует использовать свойство `background-image`.

В принципе, это поведение напрашивается само собой, если вчитаться в общие рекомендации по созданию веб-страниц: `html` следует использовать только для разметки, а любые стилевые особенности и украшательства применять посредством `css`.

**P.S.** Хотя, конечно, это не строго, всегда возможны исключения для достижения нужной дизайнерской или функциональной цели.

Comment: Спасибо. Например, фото блюда - это косметика или разметка?

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов Зависит от. Если это страница блюда или списка блюд - то это важная часть контента. Если это огромная заблюренная картинка на заглавной кулинарного сайта - то фон.

Comment: Хотелось бы еще добавить, что img обладает уникальной способностью к сохранению пропорций изображения, которой (если ошибаюсь - поправьте меня) нельзя добиться при использовании в виде бекграунда. Я не могу сейчас припомнить способа создать масштабируемый блок с картинкой-фоном и шириной в процентах (кроме хардкода пропорций).

Answer (score 3):

Хоть вопрос и старый, хочу отметить, что такие правила как `background-position` и `background-size: cover || contain` имеют аналог и у `<img>`

```css
.level {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
}

.level > div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.level > div:nth-child(2) {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.level > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) {
  background: url('//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png') no-repeat center center;
}

.level > div > div:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.level > div > div:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 1px;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.level > div > div:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}

.level > div > div:nth-child(2) > img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

/*-------*/
.contain > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-size: contain;
}

.contain > div:nth-child(3) img {
  object-fit: contain;
}

/*-------*/
.cover > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-size: cover;
}

.cover > div:nth-child(3) img {
  object-fit: cover;
}

/*-------*/
.position > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: bottom right;
}

.position > div:nth-child(3) img {
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<h2>size: contain</h2>
<div class="level contain">
  <div>
    <div>Оригинал</div>
    <div>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>background-size: contain</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>object-fit: contain</div>
    <div>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>size: cover</h2>
<div class="level cover">
  <div>
    <div>Оригинал</div>
    <div>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>background-size: cover</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>object-fit: cover</div>
    <div>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h2>position</h2>
<div class="level position">
  <div>
    <div>Оригинал</div>
    <div>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>background-position: bottom right</div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>object-position: bottom right</div>
    <div>
      <img src="//i.imgur.com/23CGEBh.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Подробнее о [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) и [`object-position`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)